# How to get to be return and print in outside function using node js

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

I tried one simple function in node js and pass data to one file on to another file.but its throwing undefined.how to solve it in node js

fun.js

```
function Get_Value()
{
    client.get('products', function(err,results) {
        return results

    })
    console.log(results)
}
```

I tried to print value in outside the function but its print undefined how to print result in out side function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function Get_Value() {
  let results = await new Promise(function(resolve) {
    client.get("products", function(err, results) {
      resolve(results);
    });
  });

  console.log(results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy using `async/await` features provided by ES7.

```
async function  Get_Value()
{
    const results = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        client.get('products', function(err,results) {
                             resolve(results);
                        })
                    });
     console.log(results);  
 }
```

Comment: I tried it but i cant use async keyword its throwing error

Comment: Whats the exception?

Comment: I have doubt.async syntax is differently syntax: async()=>{function } but function async get_value() is not working or me .both syntax or right or not

Comment: Async should be placed starting of the function.

Comment: client.get not promise，invalid await !

Comment: Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Define your `Get_Value` to take a callback function. You then pass a callback when you're invoking `Get_Value`:

```
function Get_Value(callback) {
  client.get('products', function(err,results) {
    if (err) return callback(err)
    callback(null, results);
  })
}

function mycallback(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
    console.error(err)
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
Get_Value(mycallback)
```